# What is wrong with this code? HTML5-Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to animate a blackhole simulation using the canvas element so that if the distance is greater than the radius of the blackhole it goes out of it at a changing speed.

**HTML**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>test trou noir</title>
        <script>
            var canvas, ctx;
            var blackhole;
            var circle;
            var circles = new Array();
            var G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant 
                c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
                M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)  
                Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
                pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3, // scaled radius 


            function update() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                    var vec2D = new Vector2D(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1400), Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
                    circle = new Ball(5, vec2D.x, vec2D.y, "grey");
                    circle.draw(ctx)
                    circles.push(circle);
                    var distance = Math.sqrt(((vec2D.x - 700) * (vec2D.x - 700)) + ((vec2D.y - 400) * (vec2D.y - 400)));

                }
                if (distance > pixel_Rs) {
                    var delta = new Vector2D(1, 1);
                    var forceDirection = Math.atan2(vec2D.y - 700, vec2D.x - 400);
                    delta.x += Math.cos(forceDirection) * 3;
                    delta.y += Math.sin(forceDirection) * 3;
                    vec2D.x += delta.x;
                    vec2D.y += delta.y;
                    requestAnimationFrame(update);

                }
            };

            function init() {
                var G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant 
                    c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
                    M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)  
                    Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
                    pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3, // scaled radius 

                    canvas = document.getElementById("space");
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



                blackhole = new Ball(pixel_Rs, 700, 400, "black");

                blackhole.draw(ctx);

                requestAnimationFrame(update);



            };

            function Ball(radius, posx, posy, color) {
                this.radius = radius;
                this.posy = posy;
                this.posx = posx;
                this.color = color;

            };
            Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.posx, this.posy, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            };



            function drawCircle(ctx) {

                for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                    var vec2D = new Vector2D(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1400), Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
                    circle = new Ball(5, vec2D.x, vec2D.y, "grey");
                    circle.draw(ctx)
                    circles.push(circle);
                }
            };

            function Vector2D(x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            Vector2D.prototype = {
                length: function() {
                    return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
                },
                add: function(vec) {
                    return new Vector2D(this.x + vec.x, this.y + vec.y);

                },

                subtract: function(vec) {
                    return new Vector2D(this.x - vec.x, this.y - vec.y);
                },
                decrementBy: function(vec) {
                    this.x -= vec.x;
                    this.y -= vec.y;
                }

            };

            window.onload = init;

        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #021c36;
                margin: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="space" , width="1400" , height="800">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why can't I get it to work or display anything ?

Comment: You should really format your code better. It's very hard to read and debug in it's current form.

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: // Forget this part, you formatted it. I got it to a point where you got static grey points around a black circle, is that what you want?

Comment: > I can't make it work
why, what errors you get?
Use https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar page to create working example. Peoples will test it

Comment: @carretero_1 Basically, your code needs to be indented consistently and correctly. Try running your code [through a beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and you'll see the difference.

Comment: no i need them moving away from the blackhole

Comment: Here's what I have so far. https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/djjqj1sx/

Comment: JSFiddle was blocking animations (some sort of weird error because of a difference in animation source and where it was running), but this is how far I've come: [link](http://jaspervanmerle.com/so/space/)

Comment: Well, here's something: the objects in the `circles` array are never being updated. Sure, some are being *added*, but never modified after that.

Comment: but then what should i do, sorry to bother, but I am a beginner, and as far as I know, the request animation frame function is the best way to animate them

Comment: Remove extra comma after last variable declaration at here:  pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a lot more work to actually animate this. Your update function has to:

1. loop through all the circles in each animation frame
2. check their distance from the black hole
3. move their position if necessary
4. redraw the whole canvas if any of the circles have moved.

In your existing code, all the update function does is draw a load more circles. Calling `requestAnimationFrame` is not going to work out how to animate the circles by itself. You also have a `drawCircle` function that is never called.

I have added these to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dLszL1q/3/). Another small error was in your `Math.atan2(vec2D.y - 700, vec2D.x - 400)` which should be `Math.atan2(vec2D.y - 400, vec2D.x - 700)`; and `delta` should be initiated to (0, 0) not (1, 1).

```
var canvas, ctx;
var blackhole;
var circle;
var circles = new Array();
var G = 6.67e-11, //gravitational constant 
    c = 3e8, //speed of light (m/s)
    M = 12e31, // masseof the blackhole in kg (60 solar masses)  
    Rs = (2 * G * M) / 9e16, //Schwarzchild radius 
    pixel_Rs = Rs / 1e3; // scaled radius 

function update() {
    var pos, i, distance, somethingMoved = false;
    for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        pos = circles[i].position;
        distance = Math.sqrt(((pos.x - 700) * (pos.x - 700)) + ((pos.y - 400) * (pos.y - 400)));
        if (distance > pixel_Rs && visible(circles[i])) {
            var delta = new Vector2D(0, 0);
            var forceDirection = Math.atan2(pos.y - 700, pos.x - 400);
            delta.x += Math.cos(forceDirection) * 3;
            delta.y += Math.sin(forceDirection) * 3;
            pos.x += delta.x;
            pos.y += delta.y;
            somethingMoved = true;
        }
    }
    if (somethingMoved) {
        drawEverything();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}

function visible(ball) {
    // --- Test whether ball is visible
    return ball.position.x > ball.radius && ball.position.x < canvas.width - ball.radius &&
        ball.position.y > ball.radius && ball.position.y < canvas.height - ball.radius;
}

function drawEverything() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    blackhole.draw(ctx);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (visible(circles[i])) {
            circles[i].draw(ctx);
        }
    }
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("space");
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    blackhole = new Ball(pixel_Rs, {
        x: 700,
        y: 400
    }, "black");
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        var vec2D = new Vector2D(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1400), Math.floor(Math.random() * 800));
        circle = new Ball(5, vec2D, "grey");
        circles.push(circle);
    }
    drawEverything();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function Ball(radius, position, color) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.position = position;
    this.color = color;
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
};

function Vector2D(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Vector2D.prototype = {
    length: function() {
        return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
    },
    add: function(vec) {
        return new Vector2D(this.x + vec.x, this.y + vec.y);

    },

    subtract: function(vec) {
        return new Vector2D(this.x - vec.x, this.y - vec.y);
    },
    decrementBy: function(vec) {
        this.x -= vec.x;
        this.y -= vec.y;
    }

};

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i have just one question though, i don't really get what does the visible function does exactly

Comment: Once the balls reach the edge of the screen, the script stops animating them or redrawing them. This is not really needed here (try removing it and you'll see it still works) but saves processing power, which would matter if this is to be part of a larger programme. `visible` simply returns `true` if a ball is still on the canvas and `false` if it has reached the edge of the canvas.